# Compare of values from two lists by use of regular expressions in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin, compare, mutablelist

I have two lists. The first contains original product data as following:

```
data class InputProductData (val optionFamilyInput: String?, val optionCodeInput: String?, val optionDescriptionInput: String?)
   
 val inputProductData = mutableListOf(
        InputProductData("AAA", "111","Chimney with red bricks"),
        InputProductData(null,"222","Two wide windows in the main floor"),
        InputProductData("CCCC",null,"Beautiful door in green color"),
        InputProductData("DDDD",null,"House with area 120 square meters"),
        InputProductData(null,"555","Old wood windows")
    )
```

Second list consists of customizing data. The list can have many identical option ids (first column).

```
    data class CustomizingProductOption(val id: Int, val optionName: String, val optionCategory: String, val optionFamily: String?, val optionCode: String?, val searchPattern: String?, val outputValue: String)

    val customizingProductOptions = mutableListOf(
    CustomizingProductOption(10001, "Chimney", "Additional options", "^AAA$", "", "^Chimney with", "Available"),
    CustomizingProductOption(10002, "Windows", "Basic options", "", "^222$", "^Two wide windows", "Available"),
    CustomizingProductOption(10002, "Windows", "Basic options", "", "^555$", "wood windows$", "Available"),
    CustomizingProductOption(10003, "Door color", "Basic options", "^CCCC$", "", "door in green color$", "green"),
    CustomizingProductOption(10004, "House area", "Basic options", "^DDD", "", "120 square meters", "120")
    )
```

The target is to check the product input data and to identify different product options. Whitin the following loop it is done by use of a business logic. There are 2 different constelations which can occure:

1. Option family + regex within option description
2. Option code + regex within option description

```
 data class IndicatedOptions(val id: Int, val output: String)
    val indicatedOptions: MutableList<IndicatedOptions>  = mutableListOf()

    for (i in 0 until inputProductData.size) {
        for (k in 0 until customizingProductOptions.size) {

            if(inputProductData[i].optionFamilyInput.toString().contains(Regex(customizingProductOptions[k].optionFamily.toString())) == true &&
            inputProductData[i].optionDescriptionInput.toString().contains(Regex(customizingProductOptions[k].searchPattern.toString())) == true ||

            inputProductData[i].optionCodeInput.toString().contains(Regex(customizingProductOptions[k].optionCode.toString())) == true &&
            inputProductData[i].optionDescriptionInput.toString().contains(Regex(customizingProductOptions[k].searchPattern.toString())) == true)  {

                indicatedOptions.add(IndicatedOptions(customizingProductOptions[k].id, customizingProductOptions[k].outputValue))
            }
        }
    }

    println("\n--- ALL INDICATED OPTIONS ---")
    indicatedOptions.forEach { println(it) }

    val indicatedOptionsUnique = indicatedOptions.distinct().sortedBy { it.id }
    println("\n--- UNIQUE INDICATED OPTIONS ---")
    indicatedOptionsUnique.forEach {println(it)}
```

QUESTION: Do you see any ways to optimize this codein order to get it more faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "regex" code looks broken.  Why do you test if a String *contains* a Regex?  This is the wrong way around you would normally test a Regex to see if the target string is matched by the Regex.

Ideas for performance

1. Precompile your Regex in the constructor of CustomizingProductOption
2. Your if logic is 4 logic ANDs.  The code executes first to last in a logical expressions, so arrange the first test to be the one that is most selective (i.e. have the least number of matches).

Ideas for readability

1. use proper streams, e.g. `inputProductData.map { customizingProductOptions.filter { LOGIC } }...`
2. Stop using unnecessary `toString()` on something that is already a `String`
3. Stop testing if a boolean expression `==true`

---

Now with sample code:

```
# Use Regex class here
data class CustomizingProductOption(
    val id: Int, val optionName: String, val optionCategory: String,
    val optionFamily: Regex?, val optionCode: Regex?, val searchPattern: String?,
    val outputValue: String,
)

# Instantiate like this:
    CustomizingProductOption(
        10001, "Chimney", "Additional options", Regex("^AAA$"),
        null, "^Chimney with", "Available",
    ),

# main code
val indicatedOptions: List<IndicatedOptions> = inputProductData.map { productData ->

    customizingProductOptions.filter { option -> // this filter will only return matching options to product data
        productData.optionFamilyInput != null && option.optionFamily?.containsMatchIn(productData.optionFamilyInput) ?: false
        //&& other conditions
    }
        .map {option -> // transform to your desired output
            IndicatedOptions(
                option.id,
                option.outputValue,
            )
        }

}.flatten() // you need this to flatten List<List<IndicatedOptions>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I redesigned my code by elemenating of `==true`, avoiding of `toString()` and experimented with `.containsMatchIn`. Unfortunatelly I cannot get relized your suggestion `inputProductData.map { customizingProductOptions.filter { LOGIC } }...`. Can you please provide 1-2 rows of code how to make comparison of some elements from both lists?

Comment: AndrewL, thank you for your update. The code is realy cool and efficient. I made comparison between two variants. 

1. Here is version based on your proposal[link]https://pl.kotl.in/iZFc3RN9Y?theme=darcula After 5 executions the time was between 17 and 27 msec. 

2. Here is my version [link]https://pl.kotl.in/Ya_vuki6C?theme=darcula After 5 executions the time was between 23 and 34 msec.

Comment: I think you'd want to increase the data by 1000 fold to really see if there is a benefit.  Also my one was function-incomplete because you need some more filter conditions.  You might see if you can avoid the `productData.optionFamilyInput` null check by requiring the source data not to be null and, if necessary, given the data some value that will cause it miss the filter (Null Object pattern)